# Joint distribution of two multivariate normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, independence, joint-distribution

If we define 2 independent variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as follows:
\begin{align} 
Y_1 &= (Y_{11},Y_{12},Y_{13})^T \sim\mathcal N_3(\mu_1,\Sigma_{11}),  \\
Y_2 &= (Y_{21},Y_{22})^T        \sim\mathcal N_2(\mu_2,\Sigma_{22})
\end{align}
where,
\begin{align}
\mu_1 &= (2, 2, 2)^T  &\Sigma_{11} &= 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}  3 &1 &0 \\ 1 &2 &0 \\ 0 &0 &3  \end{array}\right]  \\
\mu_2 &= (3, 4)^T     &\Sigma_{22} &= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}  4 &2 \\ 2 &4  \end{array}\right]
\end{align}

Then how can I find the joint distribution of $Y_{11}-Y_{13}+Y_{22}$ and $Y_{21}-Y_{12}$?

I know its a simple question but I could find if it was asked for $Y_1-Y_2$ or something. How am I supposed to solve it when it is like that?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @teddypicker. I have taken the liberty of formatting your question with the $\LaTeX$ that the site affords. Please ensure it still says what you want it to. Also, could you edit your last paragraph? I cannot quite parse those sentences (& what does "sth" mean?).

Comment: @gung You are a little faster than I am!

Comment: I used to scratch my head about "sth" and eventually realized it is  tweeter-speak for "something". The other keyboardism I would like to eradicated is "wanna" for "want to".

Comment: What is $Y_1-Y_2$ since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are vectors of different dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the word `independent` in the opening statement is used
in the way that probabilists use the word and not in the sense of independent
versus dependent variable as is common in regression analysis, the
*joint* distribution of the five random variables $Y_{11}, Y_{12}, Y_{13}, Y_{21},Y_{22}$ is the product of the joint distributions of
$Y_{11}, Y_{12}, Y_{13}$, and $Y_{21},Y_{22}$, both of which are multivariate
normal. This $5$-variate joint distributions
is also a multivariate normal distribution in which the mean vector is
just the concatenation $(\mu_1, \mu_2)^T$ of the two mean vectors and
the covariance matrix is
$$\Sigma = \left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_{11} & 0\\0 & \Sigma_{22}\end{matrix}\right].$$
Thus, the joint distribution of $Y_{11}-Y_{13}+Y_{22}$ and $Y_{21}-Y_{12}$
is a bivariate normal distribution which can be found by the standard
methods involving setting up a linear transformation mapping
$(Y_{11}, Y_{12}, Y_{13}, Y_{21},Y_{22})$ to 
$Y_{11}-Y_{13}+Y_{22},Y_{21}-Y_{12})$ and doing matrix calculations. More
simply, the means and variances of $Y_{11}-Y_{13}+Y_{22}$ and $Y_{21}-Y_{12}$
as well as their covariance can be computed more directly and used
in writing down the mean vector and covariance matrix of this bivariate
normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are independent, we have that

$$
\left[\array{Y_{11} \\ Y_{12} \\ Y_{13} \\ Y_{21} \\ Y_{22}}\right] \sim MVN\left(\left[\array{2\\2\\2\\3\\4}\right],\left[\array{3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0 & 0 &0\\0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&4&2\\0&0&0&2&4}\right]\right)
$$

Let

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}X_1 & = & Y_{11}-Y_{13}+Y_{22}\\
X_2 & = & Y_{21}-Y_{12}\end{array}
$$

As $Y_{11},Y_{12},Y_{13},Y_{21},Y_{22}$ are jointly normal, the linear combinations $Y_{11}-Y_{13}+Y_{22}$ and $Y_{21}-Y_{12}$ are normally distributed. It also follows that as any linear combination of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ is a linear combination of $Y_{11},Y_{12},Y_{13},Y_{21},Y_{22}$ so must $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be jointly normal.

All that remains is to determine the mean and covariance of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. Given the linearity of expectations, the mean is trivial to calculate:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
E[X_1] &=& E[Y_{11} - Y_{13} + Y_{22}]\\ &=& E[Y_{11}] - E[Y_{13}] + E[Y_{22}]\\
E[X_2] &=& E[Y_{21} - Y_{12}]\\ &=& E[Y_{21}] - E[Y_{12}]
\end{array}
$$

The covariance is equally straightforward yet tedious:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
Cov[X_1,X_1] &=& Cov[Y_{11},Y_{11}] + 2 \times Cov[Y_{11},-Y_{13}+Y_{22}] + Cov[-Y_{13}+Y_{22},-Y_{13}+Y_{22}]\\
&=& Cov[Y_{11},Y_{11}] - 2 \times Cov[Y_{11},Y_{13}] + 2 \times Cov[Y_{11},Y_{22}] + Cov[Y_{13},Y_{13}] - 2 \times Cov[Y_{13},Y_{22}] + Cov[Y_{22},Y_{22}]\\\\
Cov[X_2,X_2] &=& Cov[Y_{21},Y_{21}] - 2 \times Cov[Y_{12},Y_{21}] + Cov[Y_{12},Y_{12}]\\\\
Cov[X_1,X_2] &=& Cov[Y_{11},Y_{21}-Y_{12}] + Cov[-Y_{13}+Y_{22},Y_{21}-Y_{12}]\\
&=& Cov[Y_{11},Y_{21}] - Cov[Y_{11},Y_{12}] - Cov[Y_{13},Y_{21}] + Cov[Y_{13},Y_{12}] + Cov[Y_{22},Y_{21}] - Cov[Y_{22},Y_{12}]
\end{array}
$$

Fortunately many of these terms are zero.

Given the tedious nature of the calculations you can do a simple Monte Carlo simulation to check your answers. Here is some `R` code for achieving that:

```
# Include MASS library for mvrnorm for generating multivariate normally distributed samples
library(MASS)

generateSamples <- function(N)
{
  # Generate N samples from Y1 and Y2 with the given mean vectors and covariance matrices
  Y1 <- mvrnorm(mu=rep(2,3),Sigma=matrix(c(3,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,3),nrow=3,ncol=3),n=N)
  Y2 <- mvrnorm(mu=c(3,4),Sigma=matrix(c(4,2,2,4),nrow=2,ncol=2),n=N)

  # Calculate X1 and X2
  X1 <- Y1[,1] - Y1[,3] + Y2[,2]
  X2 <- Y2[,1] - Y1[,2]

  cbind(X1,X2)
}

# Generate 100000 samples from X1 and X2
mySample <- generateSamples(100000)

# Empirical mean vector
mu <- colMeans(mySample)

# Empirical covariance matrix
Sigma <- cov(mySample,mySample)
```

Comment: Then how can i find conditional distribution of Y_11-Y_13+Y_22  given that  Y_21-Y_12=3

Comment: Given that you have derived the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ you can easily determine the distribution of $X_1|X_2$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions